# How do I eliminate header image from subpages in WordPress Twenty Eleven Theme?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, header-image

I looked as best I could through the database, and couldn't find anything quite right. The question was answered some years ago, but the code has changed mightily since then, and the solution no longer works...or maybe it's operator failure. The closest I could find was Toscho's answer here:

[How to remove header images from all pages except the home page? skeleton theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63932/how-to-remove-header-images-from-all-pages-except-the-home-page-skeleton-theme)

but that code doesn't quite line up, either. My site, such as it is, is www.woodlandcomm.com, and I'm using the latest rev of the 2011 Theme. If it helps I'm happy to post the code the header currently is using...I do have a child theme set up, but I don't know much about coding at all. I appreciate any hand holding...and thank you once again.

Comment: In your current format, your question will likely not get the best answers. Please rework your question after reading [ask]. Here [are some additional hints](http://www.takipiblog.com/2014/02/03/the-anatomy-of-a-great-stack-overflow-question-after-analyzing-10000/?utm_content=buffer5a8b2&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer) collected to provide a good question that will attract good answers. Please take this as the _hand holding_ you asked for. Progress can be made, but the question needs details, details, details.

Comment: Kaiser, thanks for the feedback. I'll try and reframe the question. Funny that "the additional hints" section says brevity is rewarded, but I need more details...I'll try and figure a way to be brief and detailed.

Comment: Start with _"I'm happy to post the code the header currently is using"_ and the code that overrides (parts of?) this in your child theme. We would be happy to see that.

Comment: Kaiser, thanks for all the advice. The next time I post, and I'm pretty sure there will be a next time, I'll post a more accurate and complete question. In the meantime, Galen's answer seems to do the trick!

Comment: Mark, then please mark it as solution by clicking the check mark right below the voting arrows on his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the header image code in a conditional statement...

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) : ?>
  <!-- header image code -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will tell WordPress to only display the header image on the home page.

Comment: Galen, this seems to work perfectly. Thanks so much.